# Activate "Disable tiled raster layer exports" option for PDF exports in QGIS Server

Tags: raster, pyqgis, pdf, qgis-server

Is there any method to (globally) activate the "Disable tiled raster layer exports" option when exporting to PDF in QGIS Server 3.26.2-1 (Windows)?

All my PDF exports are always showing tiled raster layers.

Can I implement some Python Server code to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not implemented yet. I created a feature request on GitHub and added a possible solution that has to be implemented by someone who is able to compile the QGIS C++ source: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51238